# Aplicación Web no compila en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, aplicación-web

Hace alrededor de un mes, modifiqué un proyecto web (A SP.NET) que fue creado con Visual Studio 2017 (yo actualmente uso VS 2019), le agregué algunas clases al proyecto por un pedido de mi cliente. El problema es que hace como una semana estoy abriendo el proyecto y hay algunas sentencias que no me está reconociendo, estas sentencias hacen referencia a carpetas y clases del proyecto que siempre existieron.

[image: Error]

Como vemos en la imágen, `using LogicaDeNegocio` da error y la carpeta existe dentro del proyecto, dentro de App_Code. Lo mismo sucede con la clase `cmDB`.
Si trato de probar el proyecto, da otros errores como:

> El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'Linq' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'System' (¿falta alguna referencia de ensamblado?)

Hasta ahora probé con desinstalar y volver a instalar Visual Studio, cambié la versión de destino del Framework, recuperé el proyecto de un backup previo a estas modificaciones que hice hace un mes y sigo con el mismo problema.

Cambió algo en Visual Studio referente al desarrollo web? Porque me parece muy raro que hace un mes no tuve problema y ahora hace una semana que prácticamente no puedo trabajar.

Comment: ¿En el proyecto tienes en referencias el System.Data.Link?

Comment: Cuando abres la carpeta **References** o **Referencias** dentro de tus proyectos, aparece alguna con una alerta de advertencia ???? , revisa las referencias, a los demas proyectos y librerias, y te sugiero Restaurar los paquetes `NuGets`, si das click derecho sobre tu solución te saldrá la opción.

Comment: @RogerTorné No es de System.Data.Linq el using, es de System.Linq... en esta clase hace referencia también, pero ese error en particular me da en otro lado

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO Ninguna advertencia... es muy raro lo que me está pasando

Comment: @Matias prueba esto, en el explorador de soluciones hay una opción que dice **Mostrar todos los archivos**, revisa que no hayan referencias ocultas, y revisa que las referencias a los proyectos y a las librerias si esten dentro de **References** o **Referencias**

Comment: has mirado que sea posible hacer esto? quiero decir, Microsoft tiene una lista de lo que es compatible con qué, puede ser que no sea posible dado tu proyecto, hacerlo compatible con MS Visual 2019: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019

Comment: El proyecto está bien armado y todas las librerías están bien, es un problema con el VS porque en mi oficina yo soy el único que no puede probar los proyectos web